# Оптимизация по времени и памяти кода на Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, оптимизация, python-3.6

Есть задача в условии которой есть ограничения `Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб`.
[Ссылка на задачу](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=272)

### Условие:

> Задана последовательность целых чисел. Числа нумеруются по порядку следования, начиная с единицы.
>
> Требуется написать программу, которая найдет сумму максимума из чисел с четными номерами и минимума из чисел с нечетными номерами – max{a2, a4, …}+min{a1, a3, …}.

Есть 2 варианта кода для решения этой задачи (на самом деле их больше но эти ближе остальных к выполнению требований):

#### Код раз:

```
in_file = open('INPUT.TXT')
num_set = in_file.read().split()
max_even, min_odd = int(max(tuple(num_set[i] for i in range(1, len(num_set), 2)), key=int)), \
                    int(min(tuple(num_set[i] for i in range(0, len(num_set), 2)), key=int))

open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w').write(str(sum([max_even, min_odd])))
```

> Время: 0,093 - Память: **17 Мб**

---

#### Код два:

```
in_file = open('INPUT.TXT')
num_set = in_file.read().split()
in_file.close()
evens = []
odds = []
while len(num_set) > 0:
    odds.append(num_set.pop(0))
    if len(num_set) > 0:
        evens.append(num_set.pop(0))

open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w').write(str(sum([max(map(int, evens)), min(map(int, odds))])))
```

> Время: **1,218** - Память: 8,3 Мб

---

---

#### Вопрос:

Есть-ли какие-нибудь способы оптимизации по использованию ресурсов?

Comment: В первом коде len(num_set) вычисляется len(num_set) раз, хотя достаточно посчитать один раз и положить в переменную. Хотя это вряд ли повлияет на использование памяти, а со скоростью в том варианте проблем нет.

Comment: Да согласен, но все равно спасибо. Это не по феншую )))

Comment: Опа, код изменился :) Зачем вообще нужна функция tuple()? И без нее должно работать. Да и вообще, идти по массиву можно и нужно без for().

Comment: Это ничего не дало, только время сократилось в полтора раза, поэтому поменял

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду по элементам а не по индексам?

Comment: Ну да, по элементам. Они же нужны, а не индексы. Хотя через один, похоже, так просто не получится.

Comment: Да нет, там как раз индексы нужны (тоесть нужна сумма минимального номера из нечетных по порядку с единицы и максимального счетным порядковым)

Comment: sum([max_even, min_odd]) можно же просто заменить на max_even+min_odd.

Comment: Можно, это уже просто изврат был )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Вот мое решение:

**Время**: 0,343

**Память**: 5,8 Мб

Код:

```
import re

with open('INPUT.TXT') as f:
    num_set = re.finditer('-?\d+', f.read())

def get_next_num():
    return int(next(num_set).group())

odd_min = get_next_num()
even_max = get_next_num()

while True:
    try:
        num = get_next_num()
        if odd_min > num:
            odd_min = num

        num = get_next_num()
        if even_max < num:
            even_max = num

    except StopIteration:
        break

with open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(even_max + odd_min))
```

---

#### Оптимизация через открытие файла в бинарном режиме чтения:

**Время**: 0,296

**Память**: 4178 Кб

```
with open('INPUT.TXT', 'rb') as f:
    num_set = re.finditer(b'-?\d+', f.read())
...
```

---

#### Оптимизация через использование модуля `mmap`:

**Время**: 0,296

**Память**: 1934 Кб

```
import mmap
import re

with open('INPUT.TXT', 'rb') as fin:
    mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    num_set = re.finditer(b'-?\d+', mf)

...
```

---

**PS.**

Мне все-время нехватало памяти, когда делал `split` по строчке с числами (`num_set = f.read().split()`), поэтому решил извернуться и сделать итератор чисел. Сразу что пришло в голову - `finditer` из модуля регулярок.

А т.к. по заданию четные и нечетные числа идут друг за другом, то посчитал, что используя `next` можно будет запрашивать следующие друг за другом значения пока они не закончатся (`StopIteration`)

Открытие `'INPUT.TXT'` в бинарном режиме уменьшает итоговое время и потребление памяти: `0,343` -> `0,296` и `5,8 Мб` -> `4178 Кб`.

Результаты по времени и памяти могут немного отличаться от запуска к запуску в той проверяющей системе.

Этот же самый код совместим с PyPy и на PyPy будет быстрее выполняться: `0,296` -> `0,203` и `1934 Кб` -> `1753 Кб`

Comment: Спасибо, принято. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 2):

**Память**: 12 Мб
**Время**:  0,125
у такого варианта:

```
import csv
with open('INPUT.TXT', newline='') as csvfile:
    line_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in line_reader:
        with open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(int(min(row[::2])+max(row[1::2]))))
```

Здесь сплит и конвертация делается "руками" модуля `csv`, однако автоматическая конвертация идет к типу `float`, хотя не думаю что это скажется на скорости операции "сравнение". А вот чего память так расходуется - интересненько бы понять.